# Flutter app show White screen in release app mode?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am facing very strange issue in flutter app! When test my app in debug mode its working fine while in release mode it shows the white screen. This app is already published in playstore. After few days I changed this app. I want to release second version. When I try to build release apk its shows white screen while in debug mode working fine. Why does it happen? Is it flutter version issue?

[image: image one]

[image: image two]

here is code

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';
import 'package:tv/Online.dart';
import 'package:tv/paypal.dart';
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';


class Donateus extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _DonateusState createState() => _DonateusState();
}

class _DonateusState extends State<Donateus> {
  bool _isExpandedonline=false;
  bool _isExpandedpaypal=false;
  bool _isExpandedetransfer=false;
  bool _isExpandedtexttogive=false;

  void customLaunch(command) async {
    if (await canLaunch(command)) {
      await launch(command);
    } else {
      print(' could not launch $command');
    }
  }
  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();

  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
        child:Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),

          child: Container(
            child:Expanded(
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text(
                    'WAYS TO DONATE',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontFamily: 'TT NORMS',
                      fontSize: 20,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w100,
                    ),


                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
                    child: Text(
                      'All of our Donations are processed through Cornerstone Asian Church.We are a registered Canadian Charity (842869265RR0001). A Canadian Tax-deductible receipt will be issued to you.',
                      style: TextStyle(

                          fontSize: 14
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
                    child: ExpansionTile(
                        onExpansionChanged: (value) {
                          _isExpandedonline=value;
                          setState(() {});
                        },
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Text(
                            'Give a single gift, or schedule a recurring amount by using your Credit cards (i.e Mastercard, VISA, AMEX).'
                                'Note: Cornerstone uses the giving provider, Tithe.ly to securely process online donations from all over the world. Our Church will cover all associated fees for this service which are 2.5% + 15 cents (CAD) for all  Credit Cards. AMEX is 3.5% + 30 cents (CAD). However, if you wish to cover the fees as well, you can click on the option to "Cover Fees".',style: TextStyle(

                            fontSize: 14,


                          ),)
                        ],

                        title: Row(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Image.asset(
                              'images/online.png',
                            ),
                            GestureDetector(
                              onTap: () {
                                Navigator.push(
                                  context,
                                  MaterialPageRoute(
                                      builder: (context) => Online()),
                                );
                              },
                              child: Text(

                                'Online Giving',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  fontFamily: 'TT NORMS',
                                  fontSize: 18,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w100,
                                  color: _isExpandedonline ? Colors.amber[800] : Colors.black,

                                ),


                              ),

                            )

                          ],


                        )),

                  ),

                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
                    child: ExpansionTile(
                        onExpansionChanged: (value) {
                          _isExpandedpaypal=value;
                          setState(() {});
                        },
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Text(
                            'You can send your funds through PayPal to email livinghopetv@cornerstoneasianchurch.com',style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 14,


                          ),)
                        ],
                        title: Row(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Image.asset(
                              'images/paypal.png',
                            ),
                            Padding(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
                              child: Text(
                                'PAYPAL',
                                style: TextStyle(

                                  fontFamily: 'TT NORMS',
                                  color:_isExpandedpaypal ? Colors.amber[800] : Colors.black,
                                  fontSize: 18,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w100,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                            GestureDetector(
                              onTap: () {
                                Navigator.push(
                                  context,
                                  MaterialPageRoute(
                                      builder: (context) => paypal()),
                                );
                              },
                              child: Image.asset(
                                'images/donatebutton.png',
                                height: 33,
                              ),
                            )
                          ],
                        )),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),

                    child: ExpansionTile(
                        onExpansionChanged: (value) {
                          _isExpandedetransfer=value;
                          setState(() {});
                        },
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Text(
                            'You can send your funds via Interac E-Transfer to email*',style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 14,


                          ),),

                          Text(
                            '     cacoffering@gmail.com',
                            style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.blue,
                              fontSize: 18,

                            ),
                          ),

                          Text(
                            '     This is an auto-deposit account     so you you do not have to set up any password.     Please do indicate the Purpose for your donation.     This service is only available within Canada.',style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 14,


                          ),),
                        ],
                        title: Row(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Image.asset(
                              'images/etransfer.png',
                              height: 28,
                            ),
                            Text(
                              'INTERAC E-TRANSFER',
                              style: TextStyle(

                                fontFamily: 'TT NORMS',
                                fontSize: 18,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w100,
                                color:_isExpandedetransfer? Colors.amber[800] : Colors.black,

                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        )),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
                    child: ExpansionTile(
                        onExpansionChanged: (value) {
                          _isExpandedtexttogive=value;
                          setState(() {});
                        },
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Text('STEP 1: TEXT the word GIVE to',style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 14,


                          ),),
                          Text(
                            '(844) 329-1637',
                            style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.red,
                            ),
                          ),
                          SizedBox(
                            height: 20,
                          ),
                          Text(
                            'STEP 2: Complete the information on link received via TEXT for the first time only.',style:TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 14,


                          ),),
                          SizedBox(
                            height: 20,
                          ),
                          Text(
                            'STEP 3: Once you are setup for TEXT GIVING you can continue to TEXT the amount without having to fill your information again. Simply TEXT the amounti.e 10, 15 etc to the number directly.',style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 14,


                          ),)
                        ],
                        title: Row(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Image.asset(
                              'images/text.png',
                              height: 30,
                            ),
                            GestureDetector(
                              onTap: () {
                                customLaunch('sms:8443291637');
                              },
                              child: Padding(
                                padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
                                child: Text(
                                  'TEXT TO GIVE',
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 18,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w100,
                                    fontFamily: 'TT NORMS',
                                    color:_isExpandedtexttogive? Colors.amber[800] : Colors.black,

                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            )
                          ],
                        )),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, I had the same issue when I used `Expanded` widget improperly. Can you share your code?

Comment: @ Yakhyo Mashrapov  check code

Comment: Just remove `Expanded` and add ` mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,` to Column. Hope this will help

Comment: @Yakhyo Mashrapov you right its expanded widget error

Comment: Added the splash screen, then it is working for me.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The problem is you can't use Expand as a parent,means that An Expanded widget must be a descendant or parent,in debug mode,you can clearly see `Incorrect Usage of Parent Widget` in the terminal,it will work on debug mode,but in release build it will show blank page,so keep eye on above warning or error

**Incorrect usage**

```
child: Container(
            child:Expanded(
              child: Column(
```

**example**

```
Expanded(
      child: Container(),
    ),
```

**In Row/Column**

```
Row(
  children: [
    Expanded(
      child: MyWidget(),
    ),
    Expanded(
      child:Text("Text Widget"),
    ),
  ],
)
```

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately there can be more than one cause of this issue. One that I experienced is, for Android builds, that minifyEnabled appears to be turned on by default. I set

```
shrinkResources false
minifyEnabled false
useProguard false
```

and the build ran as expected. Just setting useProguard true and others false shrank the code as much as before; because of obfuscation.
For more see https://medium.com/@swav.kulinski/flutter-and-android-obfuscation-8768ac544421

Comment: This works thanks! but is there an alternative where we can enable these configs?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean "enable these configs". This is a reference to the Android build gradle file. What sort of alternative are you looking for?

Answer (score 3):

when i upgrade gradle version form gradle-5.6.2-all to gradle-6.1.1-all and build gradle com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0 to com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1

Finally, I got the solution as I have added in app/buidl.gradle file.

```
 buildTypes {
    release {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        shrinkResources false
        minifyEnabled false
        useProguard false
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check  android.permission.INTERNET in android manifest

Comment: #rstrelba already added like I said when work on first version it working fine and uploaded successfully on playstore on second version I just added push notification and I try to upload it second version but this issue comes

Answer (score 0):

Where should be widget library exception if you get such empty screen in releaser or profile mode. You could catch exceptions in debug console while debugging the app.

In your code, I see useless `Container` and `Expanded` widgets inside `SingleChildScrollView`. Consider removing them, it should help.

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
        child:Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
          child: Column(
                children: ... 
            ),
          ),
        ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: thanks your answer also correct it expanded widget error

Answer (score 0):

I've had same problem and it was of course, my fault. I've tried changing `buildconfig.release` configuration, different gradle versions, removing flavors but it was simple async error where data started to show before it was initialized (fetched).

App in debug mode was working fine, but in release it was showing white screen. Error was completely different from real reason: if you tapped on white screen there was a message like this:

```
E/flutter ( 6149): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception: Null check operator used on a null value
E/flutter ( 6149): #0      RenderBox.hitTest (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2234)
E/flutter ( 6149): #1      RenderBoxContainerDefaultsMixin.defaultHitTestChildren.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2596)
E/flutter ( 6149): #2      BoxHitTestResult.addWithPaintOffset (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:787)
E/flutter ( 6149): #3      RenderBoxContainerDefaultsMixin.defaultHitTestChildren (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2591)
E/flutter ( 6149): #4      RenderCustomMultiChildLayoutBox.hitTestChildren (package:flutter/src/rendering/custom_layout.dart:412)
```